# Implicit parameter resolution given multiple type parameters

Tags: scala, implicit, scalaz

I'm using a type class that requires its types `A` to have instances of Scalaz's `Order[A]`. In my use case, `A` is a Java class--in particular Joda Time's `LocalDate`. This class has a natural ordering as it implements `Comparable`.

I couldn't find an `Order` instance for `Comparable`s in Scalaz itself, so I tried writing one myself:

```
implicit def comparableOrder[A, B]
  (implicit ev0: <:<[A, B],
            ev1: <:<[A, Comparable[B]]): Order[A] = new Order[A] {
  override def order(x: A, y: A): Ordering = Ordering.fromInt(x.compareTo(y))
}
```

However, even after putting this definition into scope, the following lines fail to compile:

```
implicitly[Order[LocalDate]]
implicitly[Order[LocalDate <:< Comparable[LocalDate]]]
```

However, the following does:

```
implicitly[Order[LocalDate <:< Comparable[ReadablePartial]]]
```

As does the following after I hard-code an implicit val containing the `Order` instance I'm looking for:

```
implicit val localDateOrder = comparableOrder[LocalDate, ReadablePartial]
implicitly[Order[LocalDate]]
```

Is there a way I can get the Scala compiler to pick up this instance automatically? The implicit val works in this case but quickly becomes unwieldy with nested structures. I'm using Scala 2.10.4.

EDIT: I've also tried to test this on `A`s that implement `Comparable[A]` rather than `Comparable[B]` where `B` is a superclass of `A`. It still doesn't seem to work:

```
class MyInt(n: Int) extends Comparable[Int] {
  override def compareTo(o: Int): Int = n - o
}
implicit def comparableOrder[A <: Comparable[A]]: Order[A] = new Order[A] {
  override def order(x: A, y: A): Ordering = Ordering.fromInt(x.compareTo(y))
}
implicitly[Order[MyInt]]
```