# Avoid explicit type parameters on map operations

Tags: scala, functional-programming, implicit, scalaz

I have a `Span[A]` data type that tracks a minimum and maximum value of type `A`. Because of this, I require `A` to have a Scalaz `Order` instance. Here's what the implementation looks like:

```
trait Span[A] {
  val min: A
  val max: A
}
object Span {
  def apply[A : Order](id: A): Span[A] = new Span[A] {
    override val min = id
    override val max = id
  }
  def apply[A : Order](a: A, b: A): Span[A] = {
    val swap = implicitly[Order[A]].greaterThan(a, b)
    new Span[A] {
      override val min = if (swap) b else a
      override val max = if (swap) a else b
    }
  }
  implicit def orderSpanSemigroup[A : Order]: Semigroup[Span[A]] = new Semigroup[Span[A]] {
    override def append(f1: Span[A], f2: => Span[A]): Span[A] = {
      val ord = implicitly[Order[A]]
      Span(ord.min(f1.min, f2.min), ord.max(f1.max, f2.max))
    }
  }
}
```

The `apply` method seems to work as expected, as I can do this:

```
val a = Span(1) // or Span.apply(1)
```

It breaks down if I try to map over this value using a functor, for example, an `Option[Int]`:

```
val b = 1.some map Span.apply
// could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scalaz.Order[A]
```

However, I can fix the error by using an explicit type parameter:

```
val c = 1.some map Span.apply[Int]
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to avoid this explicit type parameter? I wonder if it's related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072935/implicit-parameter-resolution-given-multiple-type-parameters) as I originally ran into the problem while trying to use my own implicit `Order` instance. Of course, it's also failing on `Int` inputs so maybe it's just a limitation of parameterized methods.

Comment: The context bound desugars to an implicit parameter (in a new parameter list), and this makes a mess of eta expansion, so you're stuck with the type parameter or `1.some.map(Span(_))`.

Comment: Ah. Sadly, that explains it. I just tried to manually expand the function value my self by doing something like `val spanFunc = [A](a: A) => (implicit ord: Order[A]) => Span.apply(a)`, but realized [functions are monomorphic](http://www.chuusai.com/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/). Oh well.